# Is buffer overflow the only possible bug associated with program stack?

Tags: c, c++11, security, concurrency, buffer-overflow

Is buffer overflow the only possible bug associated with C/C++ program stack? are there any other bugs which can happen at program stack in a single/multi threaded C/C++ program.

I was reading this paper ([Learning from Mistakes — A Comprehensive Study on Real World Concurrency Bug Characteristics](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1346281.1346323)) on concurrency bugs, and started thinking that such concurrency bugs do not happen at stack as it is private to threads.

Thanks

Comment: What association do you make between [that paper](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~junfeng/09fa-e6998/papers/concurrency-bugs.pdf) (by Shan Lu, Soyeon Park, Eunsoo Seo, and Yuanyuan Zhou) and stack use? It contains the word “stack” only once, in mentioning stack traces. It is not a study of bugs associated with program stacks. Stack is not private to threads; each thread may have its own stack, but they can pass addresses to each other and use objects on each other’s stacks through those pointers.

Comment: When you mention a paper, or concepts or information from a paper, in a professional or academic context, provide sufficient information for other people to identify and locate the paper, such as a bibliographic citation (at least author’s names, and possibly other information like publisher, year, and so on). (“Well known” documents, like “the C standard” can be referred to simply by name.) A URL would be nice but is not sufficient by itself as URLs break as web sites are changed over the years.

Comment: Another incredibly common class of errors concerns the use of uninitialized stack-allocated objects, which leads to mysterious bugs which come and go as debugging printouts are inserted or removed, or other seemingly-unrelated changes are made elsewhere in the program.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : Thanks, I edited and linked to the research paper. I mentioned about the paper as concurrency bugs looked a major concern in multi-threaded programs. So was wondering whether such bugs are possible in "program stack" memory area. I totally understand your that pointer access are possible, but how many of those will be genuine , meaning not as a result of a bug. Thanks once again

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks a lot. I will search about these categories. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attempt to use too much stack, typically resulting in a segmentation fault (a report by the hardware that the program has attempted to access memory that is not mapped or not mapped for the type of access attempted and that the operating system does not handle by changing the memory mapping to provide access).

You can use pointers or array indices incorrectly (not just buffer overflows but “underflows” going in the other direction or other incorrect address calculations), corrupting the stack, which can alter program execution in a variety of ways, causing transfer of program control to undesired locations or corrupting data and causing undesired computations.